# Kotlin - How to implement a Class that has a Higher Order Function as a generic parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I want to implement a generic class that takes as a generic parameter type a function of arbitrary arity.

I have a skeletal implementation:

```
abstract class Action<T> {
    internal abstract val performable: ObservableBooleanValue
    internal abstract val perform: T
}
```

and a couple of objects:

```
private val install = object : Action<(Int, Int, Point) -> Unit>() {
    override val performable: ObservableBooleanValue = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)
    override val perform = { color: Int, shape: Int, point: Point ->
        println("Color: $color, Shape: $shape, Point: $point")
    }

    operator fun invoke(color: Int, shape: Int, point: Point) =
            if (performable.get()) perform(color, shape, point)
            else println("Cannot Perform")
}


private val delete = object : Action<() -> Unit>() {
    override val performable: ObservableBooleanValue = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)
    override val perform = {
        println("Deleting")
    }

    operator fun invoke() =
            if (performable.get()) perform()
            else println("Cannot Perform")
}
```

I will be having a couple more of these objects and would like to make the `invoke` function a member of an `Action` class so that I don't have to implement it for each object.
I want to achieve something like this:

```
abstract class Action<T> {
    ...
    operator fun invoke(???) = 
            if (performable.get()) perform(???) 
            else println("Cannot Perform")
}
```

Is that even possible?
I've looked through some documentation and found a `FunctionN<out R>` interface, maybe I could use it to make my class `Action<T: FunctionN<Unit>>` but then how do I instantiate my objects? Because `object: Action<() -> Unit>` makes the compiler complain

Comment: How are you going to pass the parameters to invoke when you don't know the arity? (could you instead have a fun that takes an array of params??)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has at least the following features that seem helpful in this case:

1. Kotlin has some support for tuples (`Pair`s, `Triple`s, ...)
2. Kotlin has nice destructuring syntax for lambdas that take tuples
3. There is a `Unit`-type that has `Unit`-value as the only value: this allows the abstraction to extend to the cases where no parameters are needed (`Unit` is the "zero-ary" tuple, in a sense)

Together, these features allow you to abstract over callbacks that take an arbitrary type `T` as a single parameter, and return a `Unit`:

```
interface ObservableBooleanValue {
  fun get(): Boolean
}

data class SimpleBooleanProperty(val value: Boolean) : ObservableBooleanValue {
  override fun get(): Boolean = value
}

data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
data class Color(val isBlack: Boolean) // otherwise white.

abstract class Action<T> {
    internal abstract val performable: ObservableBooleanValue
    internal abstract val perform: (T) -> Unit

    operator fun invoke(settings: T) = 
        if (performable.get()) perform(settings) 
        else println("Cannot Perform")
}

object SomewhereElse {

    private val install = object : Action<Triple<Int, Int, Point>>() {
        override val performable: ObservableBooleanValue = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)
        override val perform: (Triple<Int, Int, Point>) -> Unit = 
            { (color, shape, point) ->
                println("Color: $color, Shape: $shape, Point: $point")
            }
    }


    private val delete = object : Action<Unit>() {
        override val performable: ObservableBooleanValue = SimpleBooleanProperty(true)
        override val perform = { _: Unit ->
            println("Deleting")
        }
    }

}
```

It at least compiles. I have no reason not to assume that it would run just as nicely.